# CakePHP, ACL or Not?

Tags: cakephp, acl, profile

I work on a social web application, and I really hesitate between using ACLs or using my own permissions system. I work for several days with ACLs to see their behavior and savoi what I could and could not do.

In my application, members can set permissions on what they have (profile, photo album, etc.). I also need to set permissions for moderators who can check the content of a profile and photo albums, but do not have the right to the modifiers or deleted, however the administrator to all rights .

For the profile, the user can decide their make public, visible only by members or friends. For this, I could create a perfectly ProfileSettings table with different fields to see what information is visible and can access the profile. The problem is if I want to implement a choice according to a list of friends in the way of Facebook. I imagined the scenario with ACL, but I fear that the requested resources are enormous. Create a profile for each aco is not bad especially if requested database include 300 members, not to mention the need to save all the permissions as appropriate and user choice. So I think not allow members to define which users can access their objects, but only groups.

There still remains the question about ACLs. In my case is this a good idea? I also have to set permissions on the forums, eg a moderator can update a thread / post, a forum can be visible only by the admin / moderators etc.

Where I am afraid to use ACL is that the slightest mistake can cause serious damage, but at the same time, it allows me to set up permissions faster.

Thank you for your help and your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is probably "Yes, your use-case makes sense to use Cake's ACL."

However, I've tried a number of times to use ACL.  The learning curve was too high/time consuming for me.  I used it on an app and a few months in had the problem you mentioned - one small issue, and everything fell apart.  And without knowing exactly what I was doing / what I needed to do to resolve, it became a nightmare.  Not only that, but when I wanted to extend it or do ANYTHING other than the specific example, I couldn't get it to work.

From then on, I just built my own to the specific needs of the project.

**If you have someone you know who uses it regularly and can teach you the the ins and outs of Cake's ACL, then it might be fine to use it.  Otherwise, I'd build my own.**  Even if it's not "better", at least if/when something goes wrong, you'll understand it enough to fix it.

Comment: I studied ACLs CakePHP for several days and I quite understand the operation. In case of problems, I could fix it, but will have a painful operation that will break everything. I also prefer to create my own system, but it will force me to reinvent the wheel, so I still wonder.